# Is this how setTimeout work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want a website to refresh every 1 second, but I also want the javascript codes above the setTimeout function to execute first before the setTimeout function executes. If I put the setTimeout function below the codes, does it mean that it will only execute the setTimeout function once the codes above are executed?

```
//long code that i want executed before the setTimeout executes.

var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000);
function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1000);
}
```

So basically I want this to happen. The codes above executes. Then and only then will the setTimeout function execute - pausing for a second before refreshing the website.

Comment: Yes, that is how `setTimeout` works. You probably could have run your code to find out

Comment: ... if the code above is synchronous.

Comment: I would Suggest `setInterval()` as you don't have to keep calling `setTimeout()` just put code before setInterval and it will run first

Comment: @IndustrialComet why an interval since the code that is executed in the callback is `location.reload(true)`. You will always have only one occurence of your interval to fire.